# How to add entity with one to one association in Entity Framework Code first approach?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 4.4 + Code First.

I was trying to add a ChartofAccount entity to DBContext with the Company's key filled, but it ask me to fill the Company's CompanyName as well at validation. I thought DBContext will look up the associate Company for me, instead of trying to add a new Company?

```
    public class ChartofAccount: MasterData
    {
        public ChartofAccount()
        {
            Company = new Company();
            Category1 = new AccountCatagory();
            Category2 = new AccountCatagory();
        }

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string AccountCurrency { get; set; }

        public virtual AccountCatagory Category1 { get; set; }

        public virtual AccountCatagory Category2 { get; set; }

        public string Reference { get; set; }

        public bool HasTransaction { get; set; }


    }

public class Company : MasterData
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        DateTime CurrentAccountPeriod { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string BaseCurrencyCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, just the primary key of a related entity isn't enough. You need to round trip to the database to obtain the entity in the same data context.

Example:

```
var Company = db.Company.Single(d => d.ID == id);
ChartofAccountToAdd.Company = Company;
db.ChartofAccount.Add(ChartofAccountToAdd);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

That will create the relationship with an already existing company.

EDIT:

I completely forgot about this when I answered. Edit your `ChartOfAccount` model to contain the foreign key for the `Company` like:

```
    public class ChartofAccount: MasterData
    {

        {rest of your model}

        public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    }
```

and then set the foreign key to that new `int` property. Entity Framework will create the relationship without any issues. Don't set anything to the `Company` property on the model.

Comment: very sad indeed. Could I use Fluent API to automate this process?

Comment: I don't think so. Fluent API is used for defining database structure more than automating database tasks.

Comment: @BryanFok I completely forgot about manually creating the foreign key on the model, and then setting the ID that way. No round trip to the database needed.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I known the [ForeignKey] approach, I just don't prefer that.